# "oversight of genetic testing" or "the oversight of genetic testing"?

Tags: grammar, articles

The following sentence is from Oxford dictionary:

> Who has oversight of genetic testing?

Now, my question is why the article "the" hasn't been used here. In other words is it wrong to say

> Who has **the** oversight of genetic testing?

?

Is there any difference in meaning between them? Which sounds more natural to native English speakers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these two sentences do have different meanings slightly...

It depends on the context at which they are used. In this case to an English speaker the difference is usually non-existent especially in conversation. But, this is because you have that prepositional phrase "of genetic testing". The purpose of article adjective "the" is to define what it is modifying. "Who has knowledge?" and "who has **the** knowledge" are very different as the first one is asking if someone has just any form of knowledge, but the second one is stating what type of knowledge the speaker wants, **The Knowledge**. But in the case the type of oversight has already been defined. the speaker wants genetic testing oversight meaning the "the" is redundant.

So the first sentence is slightly more correct.

Comment: Using "who has the oversight" implies there's only a single person or body that oversees things, while "who has oversight" could be answered by a long list of different people and agencies. This is a standard use of "the" to identify a single, specific thing against generalities.